# Asus X205T Legacy boot

Tags: linux, installation

Does anyone know how to boot Linux "Ubuntu" from a Usb Stick when there is no Legacy boot option In the Bios I have Microsoft 8.1 and want to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the 32-bit UEFI is not that big a problem. Here is how I set up my Asus EeeX205T to dual-boot Ubuntu 14.10. Note that the process does require a couple of steps in Windows:

PRE-INSTALLATION

Turn off BitLocker (this will allow Ubuntu to mount and/or resize the primary data drive):
In Windows, click on PC Settings/PC and devices/PC info; scroll to the bottom of the screen and click to turn off BitLocker/decrypt drive

Prepare Ubuntu Live bootable USB memory stick:
Download .iso file for 64-bit Ubuntu 14.10
Create a bootable memory stick:
In Windows, download and run Rufus
In Linux, sudo apt-get install unetbootin; run
After the memory stick is set up, copy bootia32.efi to the /EFI/BOOT directory on the memory stick
Fetch bootia32.efi from github (?) or from one of the links listed at the end of this post.
Alternately, instructions for generating this file can be found here on github -- look for JF Well's site on the t100.

Boot Ubuntu Live:
Insert memory stick in Asus EEE USB port
In Windows, hold Shift key and click on Restart; choose Advanced Options/UEFI Firmware to enter BIOS
Turn off SecureBoot
Select USB stick as boot device
Save and exit
When grub menu loads, select Try Ubuntu

Optional but highly recommended: make a backup of the complete SSHD image
Plug in a USB external hard disk with at least 32GB of free space
Right-click on the OS and Recovery icons in the Unity launcher and choose Unmount for each
Open a terminal and run the following: dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/media/ubuntu/HD/FILENAME bs=1M
(Replace HD with the name by which the external drive was mounted; replace FILENAME with the filename you wish to use for the resulting image (or set another path as desired).)
It will take about 20 minutes for the command to complete; do NOT interrupt it, or you will have to start over!
Note: to restore the X205T to its original state, you can run this command “in reverse”: dd if=/media/ubuntu/HD/FILENAME of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M -- and yes, I have done this to verify that it works!

Optional: resize Recovery partition (note that the Recovery partition is required for booting Windows on this machine, so it cannot be removed if you want dual-boot, but it can be reduced in size to allow some additional room):
Right-click on the OS and Recovery icons in the Unity launcher and make sure each is unmounted (choose Unmount for each if needed)
Run gparted (note: this runs very slowly at this point; be patient!)
Shrink the Recovery partition as small as it will go (a little less than 6 GB)
Expand the OS partition to take up the extra room

INSTALLATION (from Ubuntu Live)

Set up a wireless connection (to download updates during installation):
Insert a USB based wifi adapter (Ubuntu does not yet recognize the internal wifi)
Choose a wireless connection and connect

Double-click on Install Ubuntu
Select language; continue
Click to install additional drivers and restricted software; continue
Choose Install Ubuntu alongside Windows; continue
Set relative sizes of Ubuntu/Windows partitions as desired (I set mine up with 8 GB for Windows and 13 GB for Ubuntu); continue
Allow the installation to complete, but do not (yet) allow it to reboot

Open a terminal and enter the following commands:
sudo -s                                 // sets up a root shell
mount /dev/mmcblk0p5 /mnt               // make sure that this is the partition to which
                                        // Ubuntu was installed
mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/boot/efi      // make sure this is the EFI partition
for I in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
                                        // transfer key elements of the current (Ubuntu 
                                        // Live) file system to the newly mounted
                                        // Ubuntu partition on /mnt
mount -o bind /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
                                        // likewise make the current resolv.conf available
                                        // via the mounted Ubuntu partition on /mnt
chroot /mnt /bin/bash                   // set up /mnt as the new root and run bash
apt-get remove grub-efi-amd64           // remove the 64-bit grub …
apt-get install grub-efi-ia32           // and install the 32-bit grub

Reboot; the machine should boot to the grub menu, allowing a choice between Ubuntu and Windows. If so, congratulations – you have succeeded! If not, and if you made the recommended backup, see the note above for how to restore to the original state. If you did not make the backup … you may have a brick on your hands.

FINALIZE INSTALLATION

Clean up Windows:
Reboot to grub menu and choose Windows
Allow Windows to check and “repair” drive C: (basically Windows is responding to the fact that the drive has been re-sized)
When finished, it will automatically reboot; choose Windows again to verify that the Windows installation is still functioning properly

Set up SDHC card reader:
Reboot to grub menu and choose Ubuntu
Open a terminal
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/sdhci.conf (note: this file may not yet exist; if not, create it)
Add the following line: options sdhci debug_quirks=0x8000
Save and exit
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
Reboot; SDHC card reader should now work

At this point, you should have a mostly working dual-boot machine. What doesn’t work yet (hopefully a new kernel down the road will fix these issues):
Internal wifi (have to use a USB wifi adapter for now)
Bluetooth (it sort-of sees the bluetooth, but not completely)
Sound (volume control appears to work, but it is a “dummy” sound system)
ACPI (battery monitor, power-saving, suspend)

What does work at this point (mostly):
USB ports
SDHC card reader (if you do the tweak above)
Screen brightness (from System settings, but not from the keyboard)
Screen turn-off after specified time; lock when screen turns off
Note that sometimes after the screen has turned off / system has locked, it will not return to the log-in screen when a key is pressed. In this case, it is possible to call up a terminal screen (Ctrl-Alt-F1), log in, and re-start the X server (sudo restart lightdm), but any open programs will be closed and any unsaved data may be lost
Built-in camera

Optional: set up micro-SD card as /home
Insert a micro-SD card and format it to ext4
One way to do this is to install gparted (sudo apt-get install gparted); note that you will need a working wifi (see above)!
Note that you can also partition the micro-SD card and install one partition as /home, and another partition as something else
Copy all of the contents of /home to the SD card (or desired partition)
Determine the UUID of the SD card or the desired partition (sudo blkid)
sudo gedit /etc/fstab and add the following line:
UUID=XXXX /home ext4 defaults 0 2 (replace XXXX with the UUID noted above)
Reboot

Optional: make the Recovery partition non-mountable
Use sudo blkid to determine the UUID of the Recovery partition
sudo mkdir /mnt/Recovery
sudo gedit /etc/fstab and add the following line:
UUID=XXXX /mnt/Recovery ntfs noauto,umask=222 0 2 (replace XXXX with the UUID determined above)
Reboot

Continue setup of Ubuntu as desired!

HELPFUL REFERENCES

http://www.jfwhome.com/2014/03/07/perfect-ubuntu-or-other-linux-on-the-asus-transformer-book-t100/
http://www.linuxforen.de/forums/showthread.php?276316-bootbaren-USB-Stick-f%FCr-32bit-UEFI-erstellen&p=1820224&viewfull=1#post1820224

Answer (score 0):

In general, the Asus x205T isn't Linux compatible due to its 32-bit UEFI implementation.

This question over at the AskUbuntu Stack Exchange site covers it:

[Creating a boot disc and Installing ubuntu ASUS X205T(A)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/560741/creating-a-boot-disc-and-installing-ubuntu-asus-x205ta)

Highlights:

> The short answer is, you can't do it. Your laptop isn't the only one. I recall reading the reason is an incompatibility with the linux kernel and the combination of a 64bit processor but a 32bit uefi like these laptops have.

.

> the only way of getting linux to boot on one of these is to use a 64bit distro with a 32bit boot loader. so, long story short, you're stuck with windoze, which is about the only os that will boot.

.

> I was able to get ubuntu to boot using a 32 bit grub with 64 bit operating system. The x205t isnt linux incompatible. Linux boots, but with a few bugs.

There are also links provided there to other sites with information on how to do the 32-bit GRUB with a 64-bit Linux install.

This one seems to have the meat of it: http://www.jfwhome.com/2014/03/07/perfect-ubuntu-or-other-linux-on-the-asus-transformer-book-t100/

Comment: I don't understand the quotes.  It should be simply enough to use a 32-bit bootloader if that's the problem, the quotes even confirm this works, let alone the fact one can simply use a 32-bit installation of Linux.  Of course I realize they indicate what worked was the 64-bit installation.  I am trying to recall the Windows Bootloader bitness