# How can I get Ubuntu to recognize Asus X205T hardware

Tags: ubuntu, sdhc

It was kind of a miracle to get Ubuntu just running on this x205t, but I got through it by following this: [Asus X205T Legacy boot](https://superuser.com/questions/873146/asus-x205t-legacy-boot/875815#875815?newreg=c1da883c45ee439fa8935d1df665723f)

However, when trying to set up the sd card reader, part of the code I copied from that post // `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all Reboot`; // didn't work. I tried inputting // `sudo update-initramfs -u` // instead.

Now it knows there's a card there but I get this error:

> Error mounting /dev/mmcblk1p1 at /media/mike/0123-4567: Command-line
>   `mount`-t "exfat" -o
>   "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/mmcblk1p1" "/media/mike/0123-4567"' exited with non-zero exit
>   status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'`

I'm pretty programming illiterate so it's very likely I'm making a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your ubuntu does not seem to know the filesystem "exFAT".
So either make it understand the fs (by installing a driver for it),
or reformat the SD-card with a fs ubuntu already knows.